# Populating a Kendo UI Combobox with big JSON string

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3, combobox, kendo-ui

I have a MVC3 ASP.NET Project in which I am using jQuery and KendoUI for the view. I have defined the combobox, a dataSource for it and I am getting results from the controller with the JSON string in correct format within the dataSource.

The data returned as JSON string is about 500kb and the combobox is not showing anything. It just shows the loading icon in the right side of it. I think the large amount of data really is a problem here...

Can anyone help?

Bellow is a snippet of my code:

`<input id="kendoCboClienti" />`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        clientiDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Clienti/",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        id: { type: "string" },
                        ragioneSociale: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $("#kendoCboClienti").kendoComboBox({
            placeholder: "Sceglie il cliente",
            dataTextField: "RAGIONE_SOCIALE",
            dataValueField: "ID",
            dataSource: clientiDS
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the JSON string look similar to this:

```
[  
    {ID:429,RAGIONE_SOCIALE:"AUTOTRASP.PORETTO G."},
    {ID:430,RAGIONE_SOCIALE:"P.G. JOHNNY IMPORT EXPORT"},
    {ID:431,RAGIONE_SOCIALE:"CONFARTIGIANATO TREVISO"},
    .....    
]
```

In jsFiddle works, but it is very very slow, unresponsive and the browser crashes sometimes for that amount of data.

Thanks!

**Edit 1:** I've modified the amount of data sent to the dataSource (only 10 records) and still doesn't work. Maybe it's a problem with the dataSource?

Comment: The amount of data could potentially be an issue. Do you see any errors in the console?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan No errors, only the GET request with status 200 OK

Comment: It is most likely due to the weight of data then. You need to use some method of paging for your requests.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan how? on the client side, in the controller or in the web service? (Yes, I am using a web service that returns the data to the controller)

Comment: Server side - do it in the web service. The data is too heavy to even be processed on the client side. You need to pass a subset of the data at a time, eg. 50 records. Then allow the user to request prev/next 50 at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep, the problem was with the JSON format I was sending from the controller. I am using a 3rd party web service (based on [ServiceStack](http://servicestack.net/)). In the controller I was 'reading' the web response in a string (which was a JSON string), and pass it further. The problem was that the JSON string returned was between " ", and somehow the dataSource cannot handle it.

So, my solution was based on your example above: I created a model, a collection and I returned the collection.

Result: everything worked perfect. The JSON returned was no longer between " " and the dataSource object was initialized properly.

Here is the code:

**ClientiController.cs**

```
public class ClientiController : Controller
{            
        public JsonResult Index()
        {
            StreamReader sr = null;
            string json = string.Empty;

            try
            {
                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("urlGoesHere");

                using (WebResponse response = request.GetResponse())
                {
                    sr = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), true);
                    json = sr.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
            catch { return Json("", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet); }

            JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            ClientiCollection collection = serializer.Deserialize<ClientiCollection>(json);

            return Json(collection, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

}
```

**Client.cs**

```
public class Client
{
        public string ID { get; set; }
        public string RAGIONE_SOCIALE { get; set; }
}
```

**ClientiCollection.cs**

```
public class ClientiCollection
{
        public IEnumerable<Client> ClientiList { get; set; }
}
```

**HTML**

```
<input id="kendoCboClienti" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var clientiDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Clienti/",
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                data: "ClientiList"
            }
        });

        $("#kendoCboClienti").kendoComboBox({
            dataTextField: "RAGIONE_SOCIALE",
            dataValueField: "ID",
            dataSource: clientiDataSource,
        });
    });
</script>
```

However, I have ~8000 records to be displayed and the combobox it's a bit slow (~1.5 sec on opening). I'm not sure if I could somehow improve the response of it, without modifying the server in any way.

P.S. Thanks a lot, Igorrious!

Comment: You are welcome! There a few things you can try, one is to take a look at this Telerik documentation: [Binding to Local or Remote Data](http://www.kendoui.com/documentation/ui-widgets/combobox/overview.aspx). There are ServerPaging and PageSize parameters on the datasource to explore. Your webservice is returning a list of clients. Perhaps adding an alphabet A B C D etc... filter prior to loading the combobox, would allow you to only bind a subset of the data to the combobox. If user selects letter 'A' then only show client's names starting with letter A in the combobox. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

Is the datasource's url correct? If you are using mvc, url should be /controller/view/. ie: `url: "/Home/Clienti/"`

--EDIT--

Here is a full example, project Url: 'http://localhost:52794/Home/ComboBox'

Controller: Home

View: ComboBox

ComboBox view code:

```
<input id="kendoCboClient" />

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        clientDS = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            transport: {
                read: {
                    url: "/Home/JsonData/",  //Note the URL path!
                    dataType: "json"
                }
            },
            schema: {
                model: {
                    fields: {
                        EmployeeId: { type: "number" },
                        name: { type: "string" }
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        $("#kendoCboClient").kendoComboBox({
            placeholder: "Select a name...",
            dataTextField: "Name",
            dataValueField: "EmployeeId",
            dataSource: clientDS
        });
    });
</script>
```

Model class:

```
public class Employee
{
    public int EmployeeId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Controllers:

```
public ActionResult ComboBox()
{
    return View();
}

public JsonResult JsonData()
{
    List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
    Employee employee = new Employee() { EmployeeId = 1, Name = "John Smith" };
    list.Add(employee);
    employee = new Employee() { EmployeeId = 2, Name = "Ted Teller" };
    list.Add(employee);
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

-- EDIT --

Another way of returning json:

```
public ActionResult JsonData()
{
    List<Employee> list = new List<Employee>();
    Employee employee = new Employee() { EmployeeId = 1, Name = "John Smith" };
    list.Add(employee);
    employee = new Employee() { EmployeeId = 2, Name = "Ted Teller" };
    list.Add(employee);

    JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    var output = serializer.Serialize(list);

    return Content(output); 
}
```

-- EDIT --

One last example of just a plain json string:

```
public ActionResult JsonData()
{
    String employeesJson = "[{\"EmployeeId\":1,\"Name\":\"John Smith\"},{\"EmployeeId\":2,\"Name\":\"Ted Teller\"}]";
    return Content(employeesJson);
}
```

Comment: Depending upon his routes, the URL can actually be whatever he wants.

Comment: @Igorrious It is correct. I've put a breakpoint in the controller, and the program is accessing it, returning the json in the format above.

Comment: @ron.defreitas and Cosmin Bogdan Teslovan: You are right, that's why I followed up with an example quickly. Hopefully it'll help in troubleshooting the issue.

Comment: @Igorrious: Thanks! You gave me a hint. I'll check this tomorrow morning, and I'll let you know if it worked.

Comment: @Igorrious: Yes, I think it is. Kendo dataSource accepts only arrays, so, given my above example..

Comment: @Igorrious: I tried different ways with no result. After all, I think it's a problem with the dataSource object (or the Json string?), but I cannot understand why.

Comment: Can you try creating a sample project with the code I provided? That is a working example. That way you can inspect the json format amongst  other possibilities.

Comment: Yep, your example works fine. It seems like the problem is with the JSON format. I cannot figure it out why my controller sends the JSON between "" and yours doesn't. I'm not using a list or a model, I simply consume a web service which returns the json in a string format then I return it to the view. Looks like it keeps the " and this might be the problem

Comment: @CosminBogdanTeslovan If you are not consuming a 3rd party web service, take a look at my edited answer above. I added another way of serializing json with the `JavaScriptSerializer` class. Double check that the string you are returning has the escape characters.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to improve the response time, you can try this...

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var clientiDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
        pageSize: 20,
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "/Clienti/",
                dataType: "json"
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "ClientiList"
        }
    });

    $("#kendoCboClienti").kendoComboBox({
        dataTextField: "RAGIONE_SOCIALE",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dataSource: clientiDataSource,
    });
});
```

Just add paging to your dataSource. I Have Combos with 20000+ rows and it works fantastic.